# VueJS/PageKit: Additional not added to vue ressources

Tags: vue.js, pagekit

I'm working on PageKit CMS (https://github.com/pagekit/pagekit) at the moment. Pagekit works with vue.js...

There is something I do not get at the moment.

I try to add values in my controller like this:

```
$test = 'MyTestString';
return [
    '$view' => [
        'title' => $id ? __( 'Edit Team' ) : __( 'Add Team' ),
        'name'  => 'asc:views/admin/team-edit.php'
    ],
    '$data' => [
        'statuses' => Team::getStatuses(),
    ],
    'team' => $test
];
```

You see? `test`is outside the `$data`-field. Now I would like to add this to my view:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        data: window.$data,
        team: window.$data.team,
        sections: []
    }
},
```

sounds strange?

Well, I took the example from https://github.com/pagekit/extension-blog/blob/master/app/views/admin/post-edit.js#L8 .

Now if I try to output `{{ team | json }}` in my view it's empty :-(

BUT: Echoing out `<?= $team; ?>` in the view works. So why can't I output  `{{team | json }}`?

Comment: Try using a computed property instead for team. It also looks like team is not inside $data but statuses is

Comment: Hi @vbranden - I do not know what you mean with `computed property`. Do you have an example for this?